# I cannot find a plugin in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

I wanted to add a builder generator plugin into android studio and I found this:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6585?pr=idea

But that isn't showing up inside Android Studio's plugin area. So then I thought maybe it had to be an Android Studio plugin so I found this: 
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7568?pr=androidstudio

I still can't find that inside the plugin list.

So, I guess I have two questions. Do some plugins not show up inside Android Studio? And how can I add one of those plugins to my IDE?

Edit: Here's a screenshot when I search for Builder Generator, it's not there for some reason:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

This might be helpful for some people.

**Short Answer:**
Enable toolbar
View -> Toolbar

For **Android Studio 3.0**:

I installed Genymotion plugin and it's launcher icon should come in the toolbar (where other icons present like run). However, absent after some digging I found that in **Android Studio 3.0 the toolbar menu is disabled by default** and the main icons(run, debug etc) are integrated in the next toolbar(just below it navigation menu toolbar).

So, to get the toolbar back click.
**View -> Toolbar**

Answer (score 1):

As refer to the answer provided from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58955525/android-studio-3-5-2-marketplace-plugins-are-not-loading).

Click the gear icon in the Settings > Plugins dialog. Then "Manage Plugin Repositories" and add [plugins.jetbrains.com](https://plugins.jetbrains.com).

Answer (score 0):

You can install "Builder Generator" plugin from within Android Stuido.

It depends if you are on Windows or Mac. First look for "Preferences" (maybe settings on Windows) in top menu.

[image]

In "Preferences" look for Plugins on the left side. Then click on "Browse Plugins" - Here you can search Plugins.

If you have downloaded external plugin then simply click on Install plugin from disk.

Comment: Please take a look at my edit. That doesn't show up for me. Do I need to maybe add any repos?

Comment: It's ok if it doesn't show. Download plugins from the URLs you posted above. Click on "Install Plugin from Disk" in plugins and install.

Comment: something i found that the plugin is installed but doesn't show up on toolbar menu. You can access it via search option(Upper lens icon)