# Android Studio 3.5.2 - Marketplace plugins are not loading

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-plugin, flutter-plugin, android-studio-3.5.1

[image: 1]

[image: 1]
[image: 1]

**Android Studio is allowed by Windows Firewall.**

Tried to :

- Turn Windows Firewall off
- Try with a different ISP
- Try installing the Flutter plugin locally

None of these work. Please help me.

What am I missing ?

Comment: I also get the error : **Failed to run plugin descriptor from file flutter-studio.jar** , when trrying to install it locally. I can create a flutter project and I can open it in Android Studio.

Answer (score 9):

after a 10hr search here are the steps to the solution:

1. Locate and open the **idea.properties** file in your Android/bin folder
2. Add `idea.plugins.host=https://plugins.jetbrains.com` to the file.
3. Save and close file
4. Relaunch Android Studio

Hope it helps!

Comment: Without manual file edition or need to restart the IDE: click the gear icon in the Settings > Plugins dialog. Then "Manage Plugin Repositories" and add https://plugins.jetbrains.com. This worked for me (on IntelliJ IDEA but I guess it's the same with Android Studio)